# Do you pronounce "j" in the word "juvenile"?

Tags: pronunciation

When I first learned the word "juvenile" long time ago (as in "juvenile literature"), all the people around me pronounced it without the "j" sound at the beginning.  They were all second-language-English learners, so we could all be wrong from the start.  But are there any cases native speakers pronounce it without the "j" sound at all?

(In our case, "without the j sound" became "yoovenile" and we were all Japanese college students majoring in English Literature.)

Comment: The "j" is always pronounced.

Comment: John, Jim, and Jane are juvenile. James is not. They all liked jelly and Japan in January. All these Js are pronounced the same way.

Comment: And Julia and June like julep in July on Jupiter.  It might be worth noting that "j" might not be heard in some borrowings from, eg German such as "[jugendstil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jugendstil)" in which it has the "y" sound of English.

Comment: When you say "without the 'j' sound" do you mean 'yoovenile' or 'oovenile'? Also, what country were you in or what language did you and "all the people around you" speak?

Comment: Perhaps the OP's erstwhile milieu included football-loving admirers of Turin's Serie A team and nine-times-Supercoppa-Italiana-winners **Juventas**, whose similarly Latin-based, 'youth'-meaning name is indeed pronounced with an initial "yoo" rather than a "joo".

Comment: Americans, especially Californians, laugh at the way many Brits say 'La Jolla' and 'San Jose'.

Comment: I was a precocious reader, and devoured _Jurgen_ by James Branch Cabell at the age of 11 (it did me no harm!) but I was quite a bit older before I knew how to pronounce its title (and hero's name) properly.

Comment: ...and it was only today that I learned that Cabell rhymed his surname with 'rabble'.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, "juvenile" is always pronounced with a "hard *j*."

There are some loanwords which come from other languages (the comments have mentioned *Jugend* [YOO-gend] and *Juventas* [HOO-ven-taas]) where the "ju" combination is pronounced with a soft of silent *j*. But in English words it is always a hard *j*:

> judge, juice, jugular, jumbo, juggle, jut, Judah, jump...

Comment: When my father was surprised or shocked, he sometimes exclaimed 'Jumping Jesus!'. I do find myself doing it nowadays.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.